# . The iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript must be utilized in apps that browse the web

Tags: javascript, css, uiwebview, webkit

I submitted my app that was a web browser that uses UIWebview, and I Used UIKit and Webkit, however my app got rejected.

"We noticed your app does not use the iOS WebKit framework for web browsing. The iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript must be utilized in apps that browse the web."

Does Anyone Know why this is?

if its because I didn't use a WKWebView how do I convert my UIWebView to WKWebview without messing up my constraints and app

please help

Comment: did you get solution to your problem?